# The meaning of the name Adonibezek

Tags: hebrew, bible

What's the meaning of the name Adonibezek? , does it mean Lord of bezek Or my Lord is bezek or something like that? Does Adoni mean my Lord Or does it mean Lord of?

> 4 Judah went up, and the Lord handed over to them the Canaanites and
> the Perizzites, and they defeated ten thousand men at Bezek. 5 They
> found Adoni-bezek in Bezek and fought against him, and they
> defeated the Canaanites and the Perizzites. 6 But **Adoni-bezek** fled;
> and they pursued him and caught him, and cut off his thumbs and big
> toes. 7 And Adoni-bezek said, “Seventy kings with their thumbs and
> their big toes cut off used to gather up scraps under my table; as I
> have done, so God has repaid me.” So they brought him to Jerusalem,
> and he died there. Judges 1:4–7

Comment: It's a Canaanite word for a location "ten thousand men at **Bezek.** 5 They found Adoni-bezek in Bezek"

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this link:

https://biblehub.com/topical/a/adonibezek.htm

You will see the majority of commentators suggest a meaning of "Lord of Bezek" and state that Bezek was a place-name, so that the king/chieftain of that area held the accompanying title.

Comment: I guess the exact meaning of the word is uncertain, but the word Adoni means 'my lord'. If it were 'Lord of' it would be 'Adon bezek' without the i in the end. For eg Melchizedek correctly translates to 'my king is righteousness' not 'king of righteousness'

Answer (score 0):

Bezek was the name of the people and place that Judah attacked.

As their leader, Adoni-bezek means simply, the Lord (or leader) of Bezek.

Ellicott is typical:

> Adoni-bezek.—This is not a proper name, but a title, meaning “lord of
> Bezek,” as Adoni-zedek, in Joshua 10:1

Comment: But Adoni-Zedek correctly means 'My Lord is Righteousness'

Comment: @AaronZac - that is true but we are discussing Adoni-bezek

Comment: but the same rule can be used for Adoni-bezek, so i guess the meaning of the word(name) bezek is uncertain